# GDB breakpoint in routine of a simple Pthread?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, pthreads

I have the following code ([source](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid) {
  long tid;
  tid = (long)threadid;
  printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld\n", tid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
  int rc;
  long t;
  for (t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
    printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
    if (rc) {
      printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  // wait for all threads to die
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I compile with `gcc -g main.c -o main -lpthread`. I am using GDB for debugging. What I want is to place a breakpoint at the second line of PrintHello, i.e. at `tid = (long)threadid`, and have the execution stop there (whatever the thread) and let me do stuff like look at the value of variable `threadid`.

I want to achieve this in Emacs' GDB implementation - which we may assume for the purposes of this question as simply GDB (don't worry that it's run inside Emacs). So far I can place the breakpoint at the desired line, and sometimes the little arrow showing the current line where the program is at does indeed stop at this line:

[image: arrow]

However when I type into the GDB prompt `print threadid` I get back `No symbol "threadid" in current context.` and the arrow jumps immediately to some breakpoint that I set in main():

[image: im2]

My guess is that this occurs because the "pausing" of program execution happens for the main thread, which is not the thread running `PrintHello`. `PrintHello` is run by thread `t` - since this is not the thread paused by GDB, it prints the hello world message and exists immediately. By the time I get around to typing `print threadid`, this thread is already dead and the program is back in main()... hence the effect.

I tried to resolve this by typing something like `break <LineNumber> thread <ThreadID>` but this is no good since in this program the created threads last for a split second. So I am never actually at a point where `info thread` shows anything except the main thread. It's simply not humanly possible to "catch" the program at a point where there is the main thread and a newly created thread running `PrintHello` - since this situation lasts for I guess a few microseconds.

Please help me to achieve this simple debug objective of halting execution of whatever thread is executing `PrintHello` at the line `tid = (long)threadid;`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, there wasn't much a problem after all. Here are instructions, if anyone has a similar issue:

1. Compile with `gcc -ggdb main.c -o main -lpthread` (yes, that's `-ggdb` and not `-g`, it appears to make a difference)
2. Run the debugger with `gdb main` or, in Emacs, with `M-x gdb` (and the command `gdb -i=mi main`)

   - Hugely important here: Emacs has by default the variable `gdb-non-stop-setting` [set to `t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multithreaded-Debugging.html#Multithreaded-Debugging), which means it tries to run GDB in non-stop mode. According to docs, this is NOT what I want - I want all-stop mode. Thus, either do a `set-variable` or put `(setq gdb-non-stop-setting nil)` in your init file (e.g. `~/.emacs.d/init.el`). Only once this is done should you launch `M-x gdb` from inside Emacs...
3. `(gdb) b 9` to set the breakpoint to line 9
4. `(gdb) r` to run the program. Execution will stop when one of the threads reaches line 9, i.e. `tid = (long)threadid;`. All other threads will also stop! Perfect!
5. `(gdb) c` to continue. Execution will stop when another thread reaches line 9. Great!
6. Continue doing whatever, we have the desired behavior now :)